# Problema de estrutura de repeticao while

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

tenho esse exercicio para fazer mas nao estou conseguindo, ele pede para usar while mas como vou fazer para guardar os dados visto que nao sei a quantidade de variaveis para cada livro, visto que a quantidade de livros varia para cada usuario

O departamento de marketing de uma editora está com o problema de calcular o
ponto de equilíbrio para qualquer livro que se propõe publicar. O ponto de equilíbrio
representa o valor do preço de venda que cobre os custos de produção. Já os custos
de produção consistem em um custo fixo mais um custo de cópia que é igual ao
número estimado de cópias multiplicado pelo número de páginas. Logo:
custo de produção = custo fixo + (num estimado de cópias x num de páginas)
Leia uma lista contendo, para cada livro, o identificador do livro (valor inteiro), o
custo fixo, o número estimado de cópias e o número de páginas e imprima:
• o custo de produção de cada livro,
• o código identificador e o custo do livro com o maior custo de produção.
Considere que o custo de produção será sempre diferente. Além disso, o programa
deve ser encerrado quando for digitado um identificador negativo

```
printf("Digite o numero de livros\n");
scanf("%d", &livros);
cont = 0;
while (cont != livros){
    printf("\nDigite o numero de identificacao do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &ident);
    printf("Digite o custo fixo do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &custo);
    printf("Digite o numero estimado de copias do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &copias);
     printf("Digite o numero estimado de paginas do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &paginas);
    custoproducao = custo + (copias*paginas);
    cont = cont + 1;
    printf("O custo de producao do livro %d é %.1f", ident, custoproducao);

}
printf("\nO maior custo de producao é %f", custoproducao);
```

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar arrays e/ou estruturas  e/ou alocação dinâmica?

Comment: entao, mas nao posso porque nao tivemos essa materia ainda, e eu tambem nao aprendi ainda entende..

Comment: Você está fazendo o cálculo para cada livro. Para determinar o livro com maior custo de produção verifique, a cada livro/cálculo, se o custo é maior que calculado até o momento e, caso positivo, armazene o código e o custo de produção de tal livro.

Comment: O problema parece sr mais de interpretação de texto do que de programação. Tudo o que precisa fazer está no enunciado, o resto é invenção.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa salvar todos os dados. por exemplo: Se ele digitar mil livros você pode simplesmente ignora todos os dados e pegar apenas o que você precisar.

```
printf("Digite o numero de livros\n");
scanf("%d", &livros);
cont = 0;
float maior_custo = 0;
while (cont != livros){
    printf("\nDigite o numero de identificacao do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &ident);
    if(ident < 0){
        break;
    }
    printf("Digite o custo fixo do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &custo);
    printf("Digite o numero estimado de copias do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &copias);
    printf("Digite o numero estimado de paginas do livro\n");
    scanf("%d", &paginas);
    custoproducao = custo + (copias*paginas);

    if(custoproducao > maior_custo){
       maior_custo = custoproducao;
    }
    cont = cont + 1;
    printf("O custo de producao do livro %d é %.1f", ident, custoproducao);

}
printf("\nO maior custo de producao é %f", maior_custo);
```

Isso?